# How do I drag and drop a .py script onto python shell via terminal without getting a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, brackets

**SPECS:
Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6,
Python 3.8.5,
Brackets 1.14**

Hello,

I am learning the basics of python at the moment and I have come across an annoying syntax error. I used brackets 1.14 to write and save a .py script on my desktop. When I drag and drop the .py script into the python3 shell via terminal, it gives me this:

```
    >>> /Users/mizty/Desktop/PYTHON.py 
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        /Users/mizty/Desktop/PYTHON.py 
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I copy and paste the .py code manually into the python3 shell via terminal, it works like a charm.

This happens to EVERY .py script I drag and drop into python3 shell via terminal, regardless of the content.

Why is the python shell giving me that syntax error when I drag and drop?

and how do I fix this? :)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It is happening because you are not dropping the script, but the path to the script. The `>>>` prompt expects Python, not a filename.

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks for the quick reply! That is fantastic information.